# Active Directory sign-in logs are not exporting to event hub even after creating diagnostic settings to export data

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I want to export sign in data to event hub so that whenever someone logs in to Azure portal the details are exported to event hub creating an event so that I can use it to send notification that someone has signed in to Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your Azure Active Directory Sign in data to event Hub and in order to get more details about that kindly check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-azure-monitor-stream-logs-to-event-hub). If you have already setup and and if the logs are not exporting then I recommend you to open a support case since it needs deep troubleshooting to isolate the issue.